# MongoDB frontend and backend date matching shows exact match, still goes into if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a service that will check if frontend's date is exact match with backend db's record

Which is as below:

```
    if (schedule.due_date != paymentBody.user_view_before_schedule[i].due_date) {
        console.log(schedule.due_date);
        console.log(paymentBody.user_view_before_schedule[i].due_date);
        console.log(typeof schedule.due_date);
        console.log(typeof paymentBody.user_view_before_schedule[i].due_date);
        console.log('Ive entered this checking statement');
```

It appears to me, that even though it is an exact match, it still enters the if statement, at first I was suspecting this was because of UTC settings, however as it shows an exact match, why does this still enter the if statement?

```
info: Connected to MongoDB
info: Listening to port 4000
2021-08-01T14:46:45.767Z
2021-08-01T14:46:45.767Z
object
object
Ive entered this checking statement
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of your variable is `object`.

Two objects are not same unless they refer to the same variable (address in memory). Good [blog](https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-compare-objects-in-javascript/) to read.

Check `new Date() == new Date()` in console.

You can convert to `string` using `.toDateString()`

```
if (schedule.due_date.toDateString() != paymentBody.user_view_before_schedule[i].due_date.toDateString()){

}
```